# Prevent SNAPSHOTS from being merged into master

Tags: git, github

I want for SNAPSHOTs versions to be automatically declined when trying to be merged into master branch. Is there a way how can I do this on github?

Comment: What exactly do you call snapshot versions? I think some context and more details could help answering your question

Comment: For example the version tag in pom.xml include SNAPSHOT